# Terminal and program run on boot-up

Tags: python, boot, linux

I am trying to find a way to open a terminal and run a program on boot using Raspberry Pi's newest Raspbian Jessie. I have tried to use the following:

```
/home/pi/.config/autostart/whatever.desktop 

[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=[whatever.desktop]
Exec= lxterminal -e [Application python3] [home/pi/Raspberry_Pi_sample_code/i2c.py]
Hidden=false
Terminal=true
```

This just gives me a big blank terminal that I can't do anything with. Any advice would greatly appreciated.
*Please also note that I have very limited experience with python and linux. Thank you.

Comment: You say, "newest Raspbian Jessie"... maybe that's what you meant, but I thought I'd mention that `stretch` is the latest version of Raspbian. It's been out for about 18 months now.

Comment: **Seamus** thank you, I know that it was a slightly different version of Jessie that had been updated in November that was put on this Pi. I have very little experience with Raspberry Pi and linux...

Comment: That's fine, but you should be aware of the [Long Term Support status of older releases](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS). Know also that since the [RPO](https://www.raspberrypi.org) "does its own thing" with respect to long term support, Raspbian `Jessie` ***may not be supported any longer***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Exec-section should look like: `Exec=lxterminal -e "python3 /home/pi/Raspberry_Pi_sample_code/i2c.py"`.

Note that the terminal will close when your script is done. If you want to prevent that add `; bash` to the command:

`Exec=lxterminal -e "python3 /home/pi/Raspberry_Pi_sample_code/i2c.py ; bash"`

If you start your script like this AND have `Terminal=true` in your .desktop file, it will start two terminals. So change it to `false`, or if `lxterminal` is your default terminal, it's enough to have `Terminal=true` in your .desktop file. Then you just need:

`Exec=python3 /home/pi/Raspberry_Pi_sample_code/i2c.py` or

`Exec=bash -c "python3 /home/pi/Raspberry_Pi_sample_code/i2c.py ; bash"`.